# Rolebase login JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a school project where i have to use JavaScript building a rolebased login system, that will redirect 2 types of user to each of their own sites. i am using a local storage for the hardcoded users ( i know it isn't secure, we are not working with any databases) and using a "authentication level" in my constructer for the redirection 
 My problem is the overall task ;)) but for now i'm stuck with this specific error `UserLogin` is not defined at validate `(Login.js:10)` at `HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.

```js
class UserLogin {
  constructor(username, password, authLevel) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.authlevel = authLevel;
  }
}
// Localstorage logins
if (localStorage.getItem(userLogin) == null) {
  var userLogins = [];
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Benjamin", 4321, "1"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Mads", 12345, "1"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Simon", 1234, "1"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Jessica", 54321, "1"));
  // Logins for Projectmanagers
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Oliver", 1234, "2"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Sara", 4321, "2"));

  var userLoginstring = JSON.stringify(UserLogin)
  localStorage.setItem("UserLogin", userLoginstring)
} else {
  var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserLogin"))
}

//And my function to validate the user ( Not taking authentication level into account yet, just want it to be able to work)

function validate() {
  // from reg form in HTML
  var uname = document.getElementById("uname");
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass")

  var userLogins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserLogin"));
  if (!userLogins) {
    userLogins = [
      //Logins for Employee
      new UserLogin("Benjamin", 4321, "1"),
      new UserLogin("Mads", 12345, "1"),
      new UserLogin("Simon", 1234, "1"),
      new UserLogin("Jessica", 54321, "1"),
      // Logins for Projectmanagers
      new UserLogin("Oliver", 1234, "2"),
      new UserLogin("Sara", 4321, "2"),
    ];
    localStorage.setItem("userLogin", JSON.stringify(userLogins));

    for (let i = 0; i < userLoginsserLogins.length; i++) {
      if (username.value == userLogins && password.value == userLogins) {
        alert("You have been logged in");
        document.location = "Medarbejderside.html";
        return false
      } else {
        alert("Login denied");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant markup (preferable as executable snippet -> `<>`) to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you have used two different notations i.e `localStorage.getItem(userLogin)` and `localStorage.getItem(UserLogin)` .

Make sure you are using same name that you are setting for localStorage either `userLogin` or `UserLogin`.

Second thing is that whether you are using localStorage.getItem() or localStorage.setItem() make sure you are passing the name as string i.e within quotes like `localStorage.getItem("userLogin")` or `localStorage.setItem("userLogin")`

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to search from variable. give it as string it works

```
localStorage.getItem("userLogin")
```

Also be care full at other places you used "UserLogin".

Comment: So you made it work? with changeing it to a string?

Comment: yes, did you get any other issues after changing it to string?

Comment: If this solved your question, can you please mark this as solved